# Bootstrap tooltip not working for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, tooltip

Tooltip isn't working idk why but it shows up like this

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        $("img[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
    });
    $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
    </script>
<a href="/forgot" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="forgot login?"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>
```

but not as the black bubble thing

Comment: Why you paste an image instead of code?

Comment: You're missing some quotes in your `data-toggle='tooltip'` selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is your `.tooltip()` call outside of your `jQuery()` function? This will mean the `.tooltip()` call will execute as soon as that line is parsed by your browser, not when the DOM is loaded. Do this instead:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("img[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
    $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
});
```

Also, make sure this script is placed **AFTER** both the jQuery and Bootstrap .js files are loaded.

**Edit:** Or if you're feeling thrifty, combine your jQuery selectors so you only make one `.tooltip()` call:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("img[rel='tooltip'], [data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
});
```

Comment: ok i did that but it still isn't working never mind i got it to work :p

Comment: Can you either edit your original post and include the lines where you are referencing the jQuery and Bootstrap JavaScript files, or create a JSFiddle? Also, are there any errors in the console?